# Angular template variable only works on hover

Tags: html, css, angularjs, restangular, angular-resource

In my template I have the following:

```
<small class="badge">
    {{reservationsCount}}
</small>
```

`{{reservationsCount}}` is returned by a promise, however, it **doesn't render** unless:

- I hover over the element
- I give a relative position with a z-index of 1:

```
<small class="badge" style="position:relative; z-index:1;">
    {{reservationsCount}}
</small>
```

Why is this happening? There has to be a better fix.

**Update:** This doesn't work either..

```
<small class="badge" ng-bind-template="{{reservationsCount}}"></small>
```

But, if I introduce literal characters, it *does* work:

```
<small class="badge" ng-bind-template="foo {{reservationsCount}}"></small>
```

::confused face:: Whaaaaat?

**Update: JS to get count**

```
$scope.reservations = reservations.get({
    future: '1'
}).then(function (res) {
   $scope.reservations = res;
   $scope.reservationsCount = res.count;
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce on jsFiddle?

Comment: Do you have a plunkr? impossible to tell based on information provided.

Comment: How would I emulate a response from my API in a plunk or a fiddle?

Comment: @couzzi in Plunker you can add some JSON file and make request to it as API call. For example, add `api/test.json` and then in code you can do `$http.get('api/test.json')` - it will looks like API.

Comment: If you add the JS code of how you get that reservations count, I can maybe help more.

Comment: @couzzi no idea what's going on to be honest

Comment: @couzzi The JS to get count is not complete. `reservations` is a $resource? And what does the reservations JSON look like?

Comment: @Blaise - It is complete — I'm using Restangular. [https://github.com/mgonto/restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)